# Runtime error while installing stable-diffusion RuntimeError: Couldn't install requirements for Web UI

Tags: stable-diffusion

I'm jumping back into programming after a long time. Can someone help me with the error pasted below. I tried reinstalling everything and restarting but the below still seems to be happening. I also wasn't able to find any other posts about this error...

`

```
Creating venv in directory venv using python "C:\Users\jophy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe"
venv "C:\Users\jophy\stable-diffusion-webui\venv\Scripts\Python.exe"
Python 3.10.0a6 (tags/v3.10.0a6:cc12888, Mar  1 2021, 18:17:49) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)]
Commit hash: 4af3ca5393151d61363c30eef4965e694eeac15e
Installing torch and torchvision
Installing gfpgan
Installing clip
Installing open_clip
Cloning Stable Diffusion into repositories\stable-diffusion-stability-ai...
Cloning Taming Transformers into repositories\taming-transformers...
Cloning K-diffusion into repositories\k-diffusion...
Cloning CodeFormer into repositories\CodeFormer...
Cloning BLIP into repositories\BLIP...
Installing requirements for CodeFormer
Installing requirements for Web UI
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jophy\stable-diffusion-webui\launch.py", line 294, in <module>
    prepare_environment()
  File "C:\Users\jophy\stable-diffusion-webui\launch.py", line 246, in prepare_environment
    run_pip(f"install -r {requirements_file}", "requirements for Web UI")
  File "C:\Users\jophy\stable-diffusion-webui\launch.py", line 78, in run_pip
    return run(f'"{python}" -m pip {args} --prefer-binary{index_url_line}', desc=f"Installing {desc}", errdesc=f"Couldn't install {desc}")
  File "C:\Users\jophy\stable-diffusion-webui\launch.py", line 49, in run
    raise RuntimeError(message)
RuntimeError: Couldn't install requirements for Web UI.
Command: "C:\Users\jophy\stable-diffusion-webui\venv\Scripts\python.exe" -m pip install -r requirements_versions.txt --prefer-binary
Error code: 1
stdout: Collecting blendmodes==2022
  Downloading blendmodes-2022-py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
Collecting transformers==4.19.2
  Downloading transformers-4.19.2-py3-none-any.whl (4.2 MB)
Collecting accelerate==0.12.0
  Downloading accelerate-0.12.0-py3-none-any.whl (143 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: basicsr==1.4.2 in c:\users\jophy\stable-diffusion-webui\venv\lib\site-packages (from -r requirements_versions.txt (line 4)) (1.4.2)
Collecting gfpgan==1.3.8
  Downloading gfpgan-1.3.8-py3-none-any.whl (52 kB)
Collecting gradio==3.9
  Downloading gradio-3.9-py3-none-any.whl (11.6 MB)
Collecting numpy==1.23.3
  Downloading numpy-1.23.3-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl (14.6 MB)
Collecting Pillow==9.2.0
  Downloading Pillow-9.2.0-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl (3.3 MB)
Collecting realesrgan==0.3.0
  Downloading realesrgan-0.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (26 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: torch in c:\users\jophy\stable-diffusion-webui\venv\lib\site-packages (from -r requirements_versions.txt (line 10)) (1.12.1+cu113)
Collecting omegaconf==2.2.3
  Downloading omegaconf-2.2.3-py3-none-any.whl (79 kB)
Collecting pytorch_lightning==1.7.6
  Downloading pytorch_lightning-1.7.6-py3-none-any.whl (707 kB)
Collecting scikit-image==0.19.2
  Downloading scikit_image-0.19.2-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl (12.6 MB)
Collecting fonts
  Downloading fonts-0.0.3-py3-none-any.whl (4.2 kB)
Collecting font-roboto
  Downloading font-roboto-0.0.1.tar.gz (2.4 MB)
Collecting timm==0.6.7
  Downloading timm-0.6.7-py3-none-any.whl (509 kB)
Collecting fairscale==0.4.9
  Downloading fairscale-0.4.9.tar.gz (265 kB)
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Getting requirements to build wheel: started
  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'error'

stderr:   ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\jophy\stable-diffusion-webui\venv\Scripts\python.exe' 'C:\Users\jophy\stable-diffusion-webui\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' get_requires_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\jophy\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpcts1w9ak'
       cwd: C:\Users\jophy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2lg61b1i\fairscale_a091169903304caf89f292450b799084
  Complete output (25 lines):
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\jophy\stable-diffusion-webui\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py", line 280, in <module>
      main()
    File "C:\Users\jophy\stable-diffusion-webui\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py", line 263, in main
      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
    File "C:\Users\jophy\stable-diffusion-webui\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py", line 114, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
      return hook(config_settings)
    File "C:\Users\jophy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-13ap864h\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 338, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
      return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
    File "C:\Users\jophy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-13ap864h\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 320, in _get_build_requires
      self.run_setup()
    File "C:\Users\jophy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-13ap864h\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 484, in run_setup
      super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend,
    File "C:\Users\jophy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-13ap864h\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 335, in run_setup
      exec(code, locals())
    File "<string>", line 57, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\jophy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-13ap864h\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 86, in setup
      _install_setup_requires(attrs)
    File "C:\Users\jophy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-13ap864h\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 75, in _install_setup_requires
      dist = MinimalDistribution(attrs)
    File "C:\Users\jophy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-13ap864h\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 57, in __init__
      super().__init__(filtered)
    File "C:\Users\jophy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-13ap864h\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 473, in __init__
      for ep in metadata.entry_points(group='distutils.setup_keywords'):
  TypeError: entry_points() got an unexpected keyword argument 'group'
  ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/46/75/5469e7e401ef3181b536d5747036ed335c894f7414f97c13dca47ea6d9f7/fairscale-0.4.9.tar.gz#sha256=802145e14e38d4b32280eab2e56d14ef153f84296f7fe2ef0e91fd4eb3d65a28 (from https://pypi.org/simple/fairscale/) (requires-python:>=3.8). Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\jophy\stable-diffusion-webui\venv\Scripts\python.exe' 'C:\Users\jophy\stable-diffusion-webui\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' get_requires_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\jophy\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpcts1w9ak' Check the logs for full command output.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement fairscale==0.4.9
ERROR: No matching distribution found for fairscale==0.4.9
WARNING: You are using pip version 21.0.1; however, version 22.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'C:\Users\jophy\stable-diffusion-webui\venv\Scripts\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.


Press any key to continue . . .
```

`

I tried reinstalling everything but have not seen any progress past this point. any help would be appreciated!